# Serilog File/RollingFile sink and buffering

Tags: serilog

It [looks like](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/FileSink.cs#L94) Serilog File/RollingFile sink flushes stream after each logger call.

Isn't this fundamental performance hit? For example [Nlog has some kind of AsyncWrapper](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target#asynchronous-logging) for queuing log events and writing them in batch'es using background thread.

What are the solutions if I want to minimize latency when using file sink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rebuilding the code yourself is the only option for this currently.

I've added https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/650 for hopeful inclusion in the upcoming Serilog v2.

Comment: Looks like that's the case now; you can pass `buffered: true` to the constructor.

Comment: Yes, that's the case. There's also now _Serilog.Sinks.Async_, an async wrapper that can be used to further reduce latency of file logging (https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async).